# Multiple group membership per ID

Tags: sql-server

I have data which contains the following columns:
`ID` where the same `ID` can occur several times with different `GRP` and `N_VO` values,
`GRP` which indicates a group,
`N_VO` which serves as an indicator of when group membership took place and
`DAT` which indicates the date on which group membership took place (linked to `N_VO`).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bMEKUMuw)
Data:

| ID | GRP | N_VO | DAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-05-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-12 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-04 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2022-02-18 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| **5** | **3** | **2** | **2022-09-01** |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-19 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-14 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-18 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-12 |
| **1** | **3** | **3** | **2022-10-01** |
| **2** | **3** | **3** | **2022-10-05** |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2021-11-08 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-06-22 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 2021-12-04 |

`ID`s with column `GRP` = 3 (bold) specify a new column which is desired (named `GRP_N_VO`).

As an example:
`ID` 5 belongs to `GRP` = 3 with `N_VO` = 2 on `DAT` = 2022-09-01.
`ID` 1 belongs to `GRP` = 3 with `N_VO` = 3 on `DAT` = 2022-10-01.
`ID` 2 belongs to `GRP` = 3 with `N_VO` = 3 on `DAT` = 2022-10-05.

As both `ID` 1 and `ID` 2 do have `GRP` = 3 with the same value of `N_VO`, the new column `GRP_N_VO` needs to be numbered in ascending order as 3_1 and 3_2, starting with the least `DAT`.

To create the new column called `GRP_N_VO` and number it in ascending order by `DAT` i used the following code:

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        GRP,
        N_VO,
        DAT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO ORDER BY DAT) AS RN
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        GRP = 3
)

SELECT
    ID,
    GRP,
    N_VO,
    DAT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO) > 1
            THEN CONCAT(N_VO, '_', RN)
        ELSE
            CAST(N_VO AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    END AS GRP_N_VO
FROM RankedTable;
```

which creates the new column `GRP_N_VO` and sort it:

| ID | GRP | N_VO | DAT | GRP_N_VO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 2022-09-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-10-01 | 3_1 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2022-10-05 | 3_2 |

Now I need to add every observations **left** which belong to `GRP_N_VO` whose `GRP` != 3.
So an `ID` with N_VO = 3 belongs in `GRP_N_VO` 3_1 and 3_2.
Thus, for `ID` 1 with `GRP_N_VO` = 3_1 every observation with `N_VO` = 3 and `GRP` != 3 needs to be in this group.

What I expect:

| ID | GRP | N_VO | DAT | GRP_N_VO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-12 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-05-10 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2022-02-18 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-04 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-17 | 1 |
| **5** | **3** | **2** | **2022-09-01** | **2** |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-18 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-12 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-19 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-14 | 2 |
| **1** | **3** | **3** | **2022-10-01** | **3_1** |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-06-22 | 3_1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2021-11-08 | 3_1 |
| **2** | **3** | **3** | **2022-10-05** | **3_2** |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-06-22 | 3_2 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2021-11-08 | 3_2 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 2021-12-04 | 4 |

-------------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------
It may be easier to understand if I divide the data into two tables.
The first table:

| ID | GRP | N_VO | DAT | GRP_N_VO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 2022-09-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 2022-10-01 | 3_1 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2022-10-05 | 3_2 |

The second table:

| ID | GRP | N_VO | DAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-05-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-12 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-04 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2022-02-18 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2022-08-17 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-19 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-14 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-18 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2022-07-12 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 2021-11-08 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2022-06-22 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 2021-12-04 |

The `ID`s of table 2 should be assigned based on the value of `N_VO`.

Example:
Table 1, `ID` 5. Every `ID` out of table 2 where `N_VO` = 2 needs to be assigned to `GRP_N_VO` = 2.
Table 1, `ID` 1. Every `ID` out of table 2 where `N_VO` = 3 needs to be assigned to `GRP_N_VO` = 3_1.
Table 1, `ID` 2. Every `ID` out of table 2 where `N_VO` = 3 needs to be assigned to `GRP_N_VO` = 3_2.

The last two examples for `ID` 1 and 2 make it difficult, as this results in duplicates, which is desirable, however.

Comment: I don't understand: how do you know that the row `3  1  3  2022-06-22` needs to be `3_1` but the second row `3  1  3  2022-06-22` should be `3_2`? In other words: once you have renumbered those other two rows, how do you know which of the remaining rows correlate? And your sample data in the question doesn't match the fiddle.

Comment: The expected result displays duplicate rows corresponding to the dates '2022-06-22' and '2021-11-08.' Could you explain why ?

Comment: @Charlieface `3  1  3  2022-06-22` needs to be in both, 3_1 and 3_2 as `N_VO` = 3 but `GRP` != 3.

Comment: @SelVazi In this example, there are two IDs (1 & 2) that have GRP = 3 and N_VO = 3. Therefore, all observations that have N_VO = 3 but GRP != 3 are required for each of these IDs.

Comment: You have abstracted the problem so much it is really difficult to understand as all the data is so similar. Also, do you not have a primary key in your table? There is nothing across these rows that is unique....unless it is all the columns.

Comment: I totally understand that. Unfortunately it's abstract. I'll try to describe it again in other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, the expected result should include rows with **GRP = 3**, as well as those with the same **N_VO** but different **GRP** (rows with date *2022-06-22* and *2021-11-08*) , and additionally those with different **N_VO** (1, 4) :

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
    SELECT ID, GRP, N_VO, DAT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO ORDER BY DAT) AS RN
    FROM table1
    WHERE GRP = 3
),
grp_3_list as (
  SELECT ID, GRP, N_VO, DAT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO) > 1
            THEN CONCAT(N_VO, '_', RN)
        ELSE
            CAST(N_VO AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    END AS GRP_N_VO
  FROM RankedTable
)
SELECT *
FROM grp_3_list
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, CAST(t.N_VO AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM table1 t
where t.N_VO NOT IN (SELECT N_VO FROM grp_3_list)
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.GRP, g.N_VO, t.DAT, GRP_N_VO
FROM table1 as t
INNER JOIN grp_3_list g on t.N_VO = g.N_VO and t.GRP <> g.GRP
ORDER BY N_VO, GRP_N_VO, DAT desc;
```

Results :

```
ID  GRP N_VO    DAT         GRP_N_VO
5   1   1       2022-08-17  1
2   1   1       2022-07-12  1
1   1   1       2022-05-10  1
3   1   1       2022-02-18  1
4   1   1       2021-02-04  1
5   3   2       2022-09-01  2
2   1   2       2022-07-18  2
1   1   2       2022-07-12  2
3   1   2       2022-04-19  2
4   1   2       2021-03-14  2
1   3   3       2022-10-01  3_1
3   1   3       2022-06-22  3_1
4   1   3       2021-11-08  3_1
2   3   3       2022-10-05  3_2
3   1   3       2022-06-22  3_2
4   1   3       2021-11-08  3_2
4   1   4       2021-12-04  4
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/enEmvDwf)

Comment: Superb! I just edited `UNION ALL SELECT t1.ID, c.GRP` into `...t1.GRP,...` to keep the original `GRP` values. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have fixed it. Glad to hear I could help :)

Comment: Looks a lot like a full outer join.

Comment: @shawnt00 Do you have another solution?

Comment: @shawnt00 I got the idea, thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

This is an other answer using `LEFT JOIN`.

The JOIN conditions involve matching rows where either the group **GRP** and **ID** match between **table1** and **grp_3_list**, or the **N_VO** values match but the groups differ :

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
    SELECT ID, GRP, N_VO, DAT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO ORDER BY DAT) AS RN
    FROM table1
    WHERE GRP = 3
),
grp_3_list as (
  SELECT ID, GRP, N_VO, DAT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP, N_VO) > 1
            THEN CONCAT(N_VO, '_', RN)
        ELSE
            CAST(N_VO AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    END AS GRP_N_VO
  FROM RankedTable
)
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(g.GRP_N_VO, CAST(t.N_VO AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS GRP_N_VO
FROM table1 as t
LEFT JOIN grp_3_list g on 
                            (t.GRP = g.GRP and t.ID = g.ID)
                             OR 
                            (t.N_VO = g.N_VO and t.GRP <> g.GRP)
ORDER BY t.N_VO, g.GRP_N_VO, t.DAT DESC
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ftiCeTZk)

Thanks to @shawnt00 for sharing that insightful idea :)

Comment: I appreciate the acknowledgement but I think you did one better. That's usable as a left join.

Comment: That's true, thanks @shawnt00 again :) In this scenario, using a `LEFT JOIN` suffices.